# collect variables and shorten code

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, razor

I am making a project, where I have to compare to rooms to each other and print if there is a change in a room.

I made this piece of code there is working fine. But the code is really ugly, and I would like to optimize the code. Is there fx a way where I can collect the variables together, so I do not have 14 lines of variables? Maybe I have to use the variables later, so I do not want to inline the variables.

```
<th class="callout-inner secondary no-changes-reservation-bgcolor">
    <h5>Reservationsnummer:</h5>

        @{
            var orderfirstName = Model.Order.FirstName.ToString();
            var order2firstName = Model.Order2.FirstName.ToString();
            var orderlastName = Model.Order.LastName.ToString();
            var order2lastName = Model.Order2.LastName.ToString();
            var orderaddress = Model.Order.Address.ToString();
            var order2address = Model.Order2.Address.ToString();
            var orderpostCode = Model.Order.PostCode.ToString();
            var order2postCode = Model.Order2.PostCode.ToString();
            var orderCity = Model.Order.City.ToString();
            var order2City = Model.Order2.City.ToString();
            var orderPhone = Model.Order.Phone.ToString();
            var order2Phone = Model.Order2.Phone.ToString();
            var orderEmail = Model.Order.Email.ToString();
            var order2Email = Model.Order2.Email.ToString();
        }
        <table align="center" class="wrapper header float-center">
            <tr>
                <td class="wrapper-inner background-color__yellow">
                    <span>
                        @renderOrderPropertyBlock("Fornavn", orderfirstName, order2firstName)
                        <br />
                        @renderOrderPropertyBlock("Efternavn", orderlastName, order2lastName)
                        <br />
                        @renderOrderPropertyBlock("Adresse", orderaddress, order2address)
                        <br />
                        @renderOrderPropertyBlock("Postnummer", orderpostCode, order2postCode)
                        <br />
                        @renderOrderPropertyBlock("City", orderCity, order2City)
                        <br />
                        @renderOrderPropertyBlock("Phone", orderPhone, order2Phone)
                        <br />
                        @renderOrderPropertyBlock("Email", orderEmail, order2Email)
                    </span>
                </td>
            </tr>
        </table>
     </th>
```

Comment: What's with all the `ToString` calls?  Are those properties not already strngs?

Comment: This question could be suitable for [Code Review](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/help), as long as (a) your code works as intended, (b) your code is real code, rather than example code, and (c) your code is included in the body of the question. If you wish for a peer review to improve all aspects of your code, please post it on Code Review.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't have to define those variables, simple pass property values to your html helper:

```
@renderOrderPropertyBlock("Fornavn", Model.Order.FirstName.ToString(), Model.Order2.FirstName.ToString())
```

You can also iterate through properties with reflection, but the code will perform much slower.

Comment: Interesting that this was accepted as the answer, since the OP states "I do not want to inline the variables"...

Comment: Yeah sorry. I could see that I could inline the variables anyways.

Answer (score 1):

You could do this:

```
@{
     var order1 = Model.Order;
     var order2 = Model.Order2;
}
```

And in your span:

```
<span>
      @renderOrderPropertyBlock("Fornavn", order1.FirstName.ToString(), order2.FirstName.ToString())
      <br />

// and so on ...

</span>
```